# "npm config set global false" not working

Tags: node.js, npm

For some reason my npm is configured to install packages globally.  I may have selected that option when I initially installed npm.  However, I'm trying to change that configuration so npm installs locally.  I googled and found this option:

npm config set global false

However, npm is still installing globally instead of locally.  Am I missing a step or doing something incorrectly?  Would you expect the command above to do what I need it to do?

Comment: Is there an alias for the command `npm` in a config file somewhere?  For example, in the ~/.bashrc file something like `alias npm="npm -g"`.

Comment: Also, there's a deprecated option that can be set in the package.json file, called preferGlobal [https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).  The documentation states it's purely informational, though.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` installs packages locally by default. If you want to install a package globally use flag `-g`.

e.g. `npm install my-package -g`

Comment: Yeah I know npm is supposed to install packages locally by default but I must have selected an option to install global by default when I was installing software.  So now the following command installs globally:

npm install [pkgname] 

I tried the command in my original post and restarted my machine but packages still install globally by default.  I tried "npm config edit" and it opens the npmrc file and shows global=false.  that should mean that npm installs are local by default right? Nevertheless my npm installs still happen globally by default.  What should I try as next steps?